# Clear the cache of FetchDistributedMapCache processor

Tags: apache-nifi

How to clear the cache of FetchDistributedMapCache processor in Apache NiFi? 
I tried deleting the persisted directory and also tried giving a new directory all together but it still fetches old data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As of today (May 02, 2023), is there a built in way to clear the cache?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to stop the DistributedMapCacheClient and DistributedMapCacheServer, then delete the existing DistributedMapCacheServer and create a new one with same port as the previous one, then start them back up.

Answer (score 3):

Inside NiFi, you could create a new DistributedMapCacheServer and point your processor at that instead. Outside of NiFi, I've [written a Groovy script](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/71837/working-with-a-nifi-distributedmapcache.html) where you can interact with the DistributedMapCacheServer from the command line. The API only allows you to remove entries you know about; in the upcoming NiFi 1.2.0 release, you will be able to remove entries using a regular expression for the keys (implemented in [NIFI-3627](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3627)). At that point I will update the Groovy script to enable that feature.

Comment: @mattyb is it possible to create a timer to create the cache entry if the cache entry is older than 1 hour?

Comment: Not currently, but feel free to write up an Improvement Jira to add an expiration timeout